# What is return type of function?

Tags: marklogic-7

I tried to get the size of document in marklogic.

```
`xdmp:binary-size(xdmp:unquote($uri,(),"format-binary")/binary())`
```

I got 90 as return type. Can anyone specify me is this byte,kb or mb?

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:binary-size:

> Summary
> Returns the size of the data, in **bytes**, represented by a binary node.

Comment: Thank You, for confirmation